# @@IDENTITY returns NULL when in transaction in SQL Compact Edition

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server Compact Edition database with a table with 3 columns: `Id`, `Field1` and `Field2`. `Id` is `IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL`.

```
const string SQL_INSERT = @"INSERT INTO Table(Field1, Field2) VALUES(@Param1, @Param2)";
const string SQL_SELECT_IDENTITY = @"SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID";
SqlCeConnection cn = null;
SqlCeTransaction tr = null;
SqlCeCommand cm = null;

try
{
   cn = Utility.GetConnection();
   cn.Open();

   tr = cn.BeginTransaction();
   cm = new SqlCeCommand(SQL_INSERT, cn);
   cm.Transaction = tr;
   cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", data.Data1);
   cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", (int)data.Data2);
   cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

   cm = new SqlCeCommand(SQL_SELECT_IDENTITY, cn);
   object o = cm.ExecuteScalar();
   data.Id = Convert.ToInt32(o);
   // other operations
}
```

The problem is that `cm.ExecuteScalar()` returns null. If I remove the transaction, the query returns the appropriate value. Using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` just fails because it's not supported in SQL Server CE.

How can I retrieve the inserted identity value? Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to put them both in the same batch.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Compact Edition does NOT support batch commands. Each command must be executed separately.

Comment: I'm having a hard time why you think you need transaction scope inside C#. You're performing an insert, which either succeeds or fails. The output of the select will be meaningless if the insert fails, but rolling back the select along with the insert doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: I need a transaction because I do more things in the //other operations and such operations must be atomic.

Comment: What version of Compact are we talking about here? [This doc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140(SQL.110).aspx) seems to imply that CE 4.0 certainly supports it - "If you want to run multiple queries simultaneously, you must include a new line character for each statement and a semicolon at the end of each statement." - but maybe not with `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: Is the sample correct? Where is code, that committing the transaction?

Comment: Yes, the code is correct and the commit is part of the "//other operations"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized the cause, the identity select also needs to use the transaction.

```
cm = new SqlCeCommand(SQL_SELECT_IDENTITY, cn);
// ADD THE TRANSACTION TO THE COMMAND
cm.Transaction = tr;
// ----------------------------------
object o = cm.ExecuteScalar();
data.Id = Convert.ToInt32(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

### The way it worked for me is by replacing:

```
cm = new SqlCeCommand(SQL_SELECT_IDENTITY, cn);
object o = cm.ExecuteScalar();
data.Id = Convert.ToInt32(o);
```

---

with this:

```
cm.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
var id = cm.ExecuteScalar();
```

---

### Also I removed (not needed):

tr = cn.BeginTransaction();cm.Transaction = tr;

---

Comment: Thank you! As a fact, the transaction is there because I perform several inserts. The class model consist of a Parent class with two specializations, so the data model consist of three tables. When I insert data I allways insert in two tables, so I need the transaction to ensure atomicity of the operation.

Comment: @Cesar Duran, you cannot say I removed the transaction, not needed. The OP specifically said that he needs to guarantee atomicity. If I insert an invoice and sth happens when I insert the rows I will be left with the Invoice with empty rows, or worse yet, with missing rows if I do not put everything in a transaction. Imagine when you are importing rows from an Excel file, if you wish and the only way to achieve the import is to loop through the data and insert each row in the invoice details. There is no other way